# Find consumption values based on previous data in R

Tags: data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have the value of production waste (`m3/day`) and also the consumption (`kwh/day`) of some locations. You can see in the output that I have total information for locations 1 to 10. However, I don't have a consumption value for units 11 to 15. Therefore, I would like to know if it is possible to find these values, based on the consumption values I already have. It's important to note that they don't have to be exact values, but rather an estimate of what the value could be.

```
df<-structure(list(Locations=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15), Production = c(239.936, 422.18352, 5.863376, 23.9936, 406.09168, 143.9616, 42.348704, 61.67968, 12.956544, 182.058268,6168.5,714.593,268.545,175.2,227.5775
), Consumption = c(467.36, 795.2, 176.2, 467.36, 
738.5, 2226.36, 107.13, 198.63, 
210.3, 1198.96,"","","","","")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")

   Locations  Production Consumption
1          1  239.936000      467.36
2          2  422.183520       795.2
3          3    5.863376       176.2
4          4   23.993600      467.36
5          5  406.091680       738.5
6          6  143.961600     2226.36
7          7   42.348704      107.13
8          8   61.679680      198.63
9          9   12.956544       210.3
10        10  182.058268     1198.96
11        11 6168.500000            
12        12  714.593000            
13        13  268.545000            
14        14  175.200000            
15        15  227.577500
```

Comment: I've changed the tags on your question. Look up the multiple imputation tag for several relevant questions that can show you how best to do this. As a quick check, the values you have show a correlation of 0.33 on a linear scale and 0.66 when both are log-transformed. So there is some information for an imputation process to take advantage of, though whether it is enough to be useful depends on your goals.

Comment: Thanks for tips @mkt, so it doesn't have to be exact consumption values for locations 11 to 15, it's more to have an average of these values.